# Mod_rewrite mode Apache URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, base64

I have a url that is 
www.mydomain.com/category_result.php?Category_Id=MQ==

and would like to create a way when my user type
www.mydomain.com/Brazil redirect me to the link above

How could I archive this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To leave the '/Brazil' up in their browser bar, do an internal rewrite (assumes you are adding these rules an httpd.conf and not .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^/Brazil$ /category_result.php?Category_Id=MQ==
```

To redirect:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^/Brazil$ http://www.mydomain.com/category_result.php?Category_Id=MQ== [R]
```

But you don't actually need mod_rewrite to do this operation:

```
Redirect /Brazil http://www.mydomain.com/category_result.php?Category_Id=MQ==
```